# How to stop yii2 from surfing into my commented code

Tags: yii2

How to prevent Yii2 from compiling commented code.

I am new to yii2 and I need to comment some code for later use. Of course the commented code is not working (And that is why it is commented for now) but yii2 prompts errors from amongst them.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="javascript:void();" id="link_customer_stat">آمار</a>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href="javascript:void();" id="link_customer_details">مشخصات</a>
  </li>
  <!--
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void();" id="link_customer_orders">سفارش ها: <?=$model['dataProviderCourierOrders_totalConut']?> </a>
  </li>
  -->
  <li class="disabled">
       <a href="javascript:void();" id="link_customer_messages">پیام ها </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I get:

```
Undefined Index: dataProviderCourierOrders_totalConut
```

Is there a way to stop the commeted code from getting processed in yii2?

Comment: Can you show us an example?

Comment: @mrateb Yes I just added the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the proper comment for php  too eg:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="javascript:void();" id="link_customer_stat">آمار</a>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href="javascript:void();" id="link_customer_details">مشخصات</a>
  </li>
  <!--
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void();" id="link_customer_orders">سفارش ها: 
          <?php // echo $model['dataProviderCourierOrders_totalConut'] ?> </a>
  </li>
  -->
  <li class="disabled">
       <a href="javascript:void();" id="link_customer_messages">پیام ها </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

**First** solution to comment **html** with **php code** show below example

use `<?php /* Comment Html or PHP Code Here */ ?>` show below

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
 <li class="active">
   <a href="javascript:void();" id="link_customer_stat">آمار</a>
 </li>
 <li>
   <a href="javascript:void();" id="link_customer_details">مشخصات</a>
 </li>
 <?php /*
 <li>
   <a href="javascript:void();" id="link_customer_orders">سفارش ها: <?=$model['dataProviderCourierOrders_totalConut']?> </a>
 </li>
 */ ?>
 <li class="disabled">
   <a href="javascript:void();" id="link_customer_messages">پیام ها </a>
 </li>
```

**Second** solution to comment only **php** code show below example

use `<?= PHP Code ?>` to `<?php // PHP Code ?>` show below

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
 <li class="active">
   <a href="javascript:void();" id="link_customer_stat">آمار</a>
 </li>
 <li>
   <a href="javascript:void();" id="link_customer_details">مشخصات</a>
 </li>
 <!--
 <li>
   <a href="javascript:void();" id="link_customer_orders">سفارش ها: <?php // $model['dataProviderCourierOrders_totalConut'] ?> </a>
 </li>
 -->
 <li class="disabled">
   <a href="javascript:void();" id="link_customer_messages">پیام ها </a>
 </li>
```

Refer [Yii 2 Core Framework Code Style](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/internals/core-code-style.md) maybe help full to you